# pytest --capture=fd : where is the file created?

Tags: python, pytest

According to pytest's documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing):

> `pytest --capture=fd  # also point filedescriptors 1 and 2 to temp file`

The way I interpret this is that pytest's output to *stdout* and *stderr* are also captured to a temp file. But I can't find that file or specify it.

The smaller question is *Where is the file when using `--capture=fd` in pytest?*

The bigger question is *How can I capture pytest's output to a file **using a pytest option**?*

I'm calling `pytest.main(<options>)` in a script, hence wanting a pytest option, vs capturing with `tee` (which would work well).

Comment: Used the solution in this link (the first one was enough), but seems a bit hacky.. sure prefer to use pytest's native functionality where possible. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/